Risk Aversion Coefficient Literature Rationale and Sources
I'm running a Black-Litterman model and for the Risk Aversion Coefficient I have two potential formulas.
The first is the standard formula which I believe is used in the original Black-Litterman formula:

The second is a variation of the first. But this time the variance is multiplied by 2.

Does anyone know why we would multiply variance by 2, and who is the source? I'm struggling to find one.
As an aside, the second equation provides a more reasonable value for risk aversion with my data than the first. I discovered it in an lecturer's old notes.

In some sources, the optimization problem takes the general form $\mu-\lambda\sigma^2$, in others it is $\mu-\frac{1}{2}\lambda\sigma^2$.
